# How to add a special row to `<asp:GridView>`?

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, aspxgridview

I'd like to add a special row at the bottom of `<asp:GridView>`. The template of this row is different from the rows above. How can I make this?

[image]

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @lzzy, Currently I just used textbox and button controls outside the gridview. I wonder if I could move these controls into the gridview so that it looks more integrated.

Comment: Yes you can achieve that. Look [here](https://csaspnetgridview.codeplex.com/) it should give you a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the footer template if you always want your 'add' row to be at the bottom of the table:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>

    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Alan and @lzzy. I made it using `<FooterTemplate>`.

```
<!-- ASPX -->
<asp:GridView ID="UserGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnRowDeleting="UserGridView_OnRowDeleting" 
            OnRowCommand="UserGridView_OnRowCommand" ShowFooter="true">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username" ItemStyle-Width="70">
                    <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="Username" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>'/> </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NewUsername"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender" ItemStyle-Width="70">
                    <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="Gender" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'/></ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="NewGender" runat="server" >
                            <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="AddUserButton" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandName="Add"/>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

---

```
// CSS
protected void UserGridView_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Add")
    {
        TextBox newUsername = (TextBox) UserGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewUsername");
        DropDownList newGender = (DropDownList)UserGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewGender");
        AddUser(newGender.SelectedValue, newUsername.Text);
        BindUserData();
    }
}

protected void UserGridView_OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string username = e.Values["Username"].ToString();
    string gender = e.Values["Gender"].ToString();
    DeleteUser(gender, username);
    BindUserData();
}
```

Some other problem I met along the way and keys to them. In case someone need them.

---

***How to bind data to `<asp:Label>`?***
Use `<%# Bind("DataFieldName") %>`.

**Example:**

```
<ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="Username" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>'/> </ItemTemplate>
```

---

***Why isn't the footer showing?***
Set `ShowFooter="true"` in `<asp:GridView>`.

---

***How to get the reference to controls in footer?***
**Example:**

```
TextBox newUsername = (TextBox)UserGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewUsername");
```

---

***How to bind the AddUserButton as the default button?***
**Example:**

```
MainForm.DefaultButton = UserGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("AddUserButton").UniqueID;
```